# Show $A_n$ is invariant under conjugation $\pi \in S_n , \pi A_n \pi^{-1} =A_n $

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show $A_n$ is invariant under conjugation

$$\pi \in S_n , \pi A_n \pi^{-1}  =A_n $$

---

$\Rightarrow$] ($\pi A_n \pi^{-1} \subset A_n$)

$x \in S_n $, $x\in \pi A_n \pi^{-1}$ so $\pi x \pi^{-1} \in A_n$ conjugation is a famous automophism $x \in A_n$

another argument would be  $\pi x \pi^{-1}$ is even set it equal to $\sigma_{even}$ so $x =  \pi^{-1} \sigma \pi $

we go into cases if $\pi$ is even or odd, either case $x$ is even

$\Leftarrow $ similar argument

---

**Studying for a test appreciate feedback, thanks**

Comment: $\pi A_n \pi^{-1}$ has the same cardinality as $A_n$. So, it is enough to show that it is a subset of $A_n$. Well, if we consider any $\pi \in S_n$ and any $\sigma \in A_n$ then what is the parity of $\pi \sigma \pi^{-1}$ (even or odd)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I genuinely don't understand anything you've written down. How about if we try this:

Since $S_n$ is generated by transpositions, it is enough to show that $\tau A_n\tau=A_n$ when $\tau=\tau^{-1}$ is a transposition. Now, if $\sigma\in A_n$, then $\sigma$ can be written as a product of an even number of transpositions, say
$$\sigma=\tau_1\cdots\tau_{2k}.$$
Now, $\tau\sigma\tau=\tau(\tau_1\cdots\tau_{2k})\tau$ is a product of $2k+2$ transpositions, hence belongs to $A_n$.

This shows that $\tau A_n\tau\subset A_n$. But, both sets have order $n!/2$, so they are equal.